# Lost visudo - I seem to have lost visudo, to my great surprise

Tags: visudo

Lost `visudo`

I seem to have lost `visudo`, to my great surprise.  I'm trying to add to `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d` but when I try and run `visudo` as root I get this

```
sudo: visudo: command not found
```

when I search I get this

```
whereis visudo 
visudo: /usr/share/man/man8/visudo.8.gz
```

So the packed file is there but for some reason was either not unpacked or has been lost. `sudo` works fine.

If I try `visudo` as a command I get this

```
visudo 
The program 'visudo' can be found in the following packages: 
 * sudo 
 * sudo-ldap 
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I'm unsure if trying  `sudo apt-get install sudo` will solve the problem or just give more problems.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -l /usr/sbin/visudo` and `sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'` to your question.

Comment: `/usr/share/man/man8/visudo.8.gz` is not the packed file, it's the man page of the command.  Your executable should be in `/usr/sbin/visudo`. Reinstalling sudo will probably remove your modifications to `/etc/sudores` (but should not touch files added under `/etc/sudoers.d/`).